# About Setting Up Selenium project with Eclipse and/or without Maven

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm a complete beginner just trying to create a Selenium Webdriver project, I think with ChromeDriver or HTMLUnitDriver. Please tell me If I'm correct. I've read that to setup a Selenium Webdriver project I could do that by creating a Maven project In netbeans, and configure the pom.xml file to download the dependencies. But I don't really know where to start, or how to configure Maven properly at this time.

That makes me think... Is Maven mandatory ? To create a Selenium project I MUST have to deal with Maven ? It's possible to just download the libraries (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and Include them into the "Global Libraries" section, and adding then the library to the project "libraries" folder and use import clauses to use one package or another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Maven mandatory?

No! it's not

> It's possible to just download the libraries and Include them?

yes it is possible!

Maven will do the same thing! (simplified) it creates a library with all the jars in it and adds this to your project.

Comment: Ty for the quick answer. ;) I've just needed to add the *"selenium-java-2.37.0.jar"* file to the classpath and all of the /lib jars

Answer (score 2):

Great! It's great to see another beginner to Selenium WebDriver!  I'd like to recommend a project that can help you get started.

You can download it [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip), or check it out from github, [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium)

It isn't required to use Maven, but it **IS** highly recommended to use some sort of dependency management software like Maven, Ant, or others. **Why?** Because say you have a jar file, and you have multiple contributors.  How will those contributors get the dependency? would they have to download the jar themselves? and how would you know that they downloaded the right version?!

The getting-started-with-selenium project I just gave you, is a personal project i've been working on for a while now, and it has the things that I wish **I** had when i was starting with Selenium 2 WebDriver with Java.  It also uses a concept that I implement in real-life scenarios with real-life regression systems.

Since you're new, you've probably noticed all kinds of examples that use `driver.findElement(blah).click()` and all kinds of ugly stuff like this. This framework in particular abstracts you from all that confusion just by providing methods (which you can call fluently).

This project actually **does** use maven, and you can see an active example of how maven works together with Java, and jUnit to provide a nice framework.

Here is an example that is included with the framework -

```
/**
 * This is a sample test that can get you started.
 * <br><br>
 * This test shows how you can use the concept of "method chaining" to create successful, and independent tests, as well as the validations method that can get you started.
 * @author ddavison
 *
 */

@Config(url = "http://ddavison.github.io/tests/getting-started-with-selenium.htm", browser = Browser.FIREFOX) // You are able to specify a "base url" for your test, from which you will test. You may leave `browser` blank.
public class SampleFunctionalTest extends AutomationTest {

    /**
     * You are able to fire this test right up and see it in action.  Right click the test() method, and click "Run As... jUnit test".
     * 
     * The purpose of this is to show you how you can continue testing, just by taking the semi colon out, and continuing with your test.
     */
    @Test
    public void test() {

            // click / validateAttribute
        click(props.get("click"))
        .validateAttribute(props.get("click"), "class", "success") // validate that the class indeed added.

        // setText / validateText
        .setText(By.id("setTextField"), "woot!")
        .validateText(By.id("setTextField"), "woot!") // validates that it indeed set.

        // check / uncheck
        .check(By.id("checkbox"))
        .validateChecked(By.id("checkbox")) // validate that it checked

        .check(props.get("radio.2")) // remember that props come from <class name>.properties, and are always CSS selectors. (why use anything else, honestly.)
        .validateUnchecked(props.get("radio.1")) // since radio 1 was selected by default, check the second one, then validate that the first radio is no longer checked.

        // select from dropdowns.
        .selectOptionByText(By.xpath("//select[@id='select']"), "Second") // just as a proof of concept that you can select on anything. But don't use xpath!!
        .validateText(By.id("select"), "2") // validateText() will actually return the value="" attr of a dropdown, so that's why 2 works but "Second" will not.

        .selectOptionByValue(By.cssSelector("select#select"), "3")
        .validateText(props.get("select"), "3")

        // frames
        .switchToFrame("frame") // the id="frame"
        .validatePresent(By.cssSelector("div#frame_content"))

        // windows
        .switchToWindow("Getting Started with Selenium") // switch back to the test window.
        .click(By.linkText("Open a new tab / window"))
        .waitForWindow("Google") // waits for the url.  Can also be the you are expecting. :) (regex enabled too)
        .setText(By.name("q"), "google!")
        .closeWindow(); // we've closed google, and back on the getting started with selenium page.

    }
}
```

Simple! no?  If you do need help with this framework provided, i can help you out.